# alert_dialog_icon not found with drawable

Tags: android, drawable, menuitem

I am trying to do an example of menu item

```
MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Item 1");
    {
        mnu1.setAlphabeticShortcut('a');
        mnu1.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon);            
    }
```

But in my eclipse i am not able to find `alert_dialog_icon`.
Can anybody please explain me why this is happening. I am able to use only `ic_launcher`.

Comment: Because there's no alert_dialog_icon in your drawable folder, when you will use this R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon, it will look up into your drawable folder. Make sure there's alert_dialog_icon file in your drawable folder. If it's already there please clean your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a drawable resource (either a PNG, or an XML drawable) in your project (or linked to your project) with the name: alert_dialog_icon.

Comment: so drawable mean image from res/drawable  folders am i right. I am totally new with Android so am asking so silly questions.

Comment: Yes, you will need a resource in your res/drawables/ folder with the name you are using.  You will notice the ic_launcher icon in those folders.

Comment: On eclipse, select File\New\Android Icon Set - which will open a wizard to allow you to create these drawable resources easily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check 3 things.

First Check whether `alert_dialog_icon` exists in any `drawable` folder or not.

Secondly Check which `R` Class you have imported.

Third Clean your Project and build the Project. This time it should work if above both are fine.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by others you may need to add your own images to project.

BUT ...

If you don't want to add your own resource to the "res" folder (for example - you're just trying and testing stuff) you can use some of the resources that come with Android - just use the "android.R.drawable.*" ... although it is not recommended - some of those images may become unavailable (which I doubt) in the distant future - but for testing is fine.

Her is an example ...

```
mnu1.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
```